# How to identify when a USB device is inserted to a WinCE device

Tags: usb, windows-ce, detection

I have a touch enabled device with WinCE, I need to show a UI whenever a USB device is inserted to the device. If there any event or method to identify the USB insertion in WinCE.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to monitor just USB sticks you can use [RequestDeviceNotifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms919831.aspx) for block devices.

What kind of devices can be plugged to the USB?

You can also change the USB driver code to signal an event whenever it gets an interrupt and you can wait for that event.

Answer (score 1):

This website [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/BruceEitman/archive/2008/06/13/windows-ce-monitoring-for-disk-insertion-to-add-support-for.aspx) has the exact code you need, I tested it and it works on Windows CE 6

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you have to register a `SystemState` handler for a `SystemProperty`.

Comment: I cant get you, can you please explain more briefly. It will be more pleasing if you can give a sample code or reference

Answer (score 0):

If you're using managed code and the SDF, then it's already plumbed in for you with the `DeviceStatusMonitor` class.  [This blog entry](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2009/04/20/DetectingDiskInsertionAndRemovalInTheCompactFramework.aspx) shows how to detect USB Disks, but other devices can be watched by simply changing the device class you're looking for.